# Have External Lists And / Or Event Receivers?

Tags: 2010, custom-list, event-receivers, external-list

I am fairly new to Sharepoint. I am in the early stages of developing a SP2010 LOB app that will finally have like 50 lists which are quite interrelated with each other. I am asking  for your help with a design choice that (I believe) I need to make:

Given the number of lists, their heavy interdependency and the need for various rather complex queries I'd like to organize the SP lists as external lists, allowing me to make use of SQL server features like sprocs, joined queries etc.

On the other hand, the solution will rely heavily on event receivers of one sort or the other - and it seems external lists cannot have event reveivers.

The way I understand the situation I could either
a) forget the external lists (in favor of SP-internal lists) and therefore give up the SQL server features, but have event receivers, or 
b) hang on to my external lists, code all CRUD ops manually (BDC model) and hook home-grown event receivers into those CRUD operations. Given the coding and maintenance effort, not a pretty prospect either.

So please, what do you experts think? Is my initial analysis correct at all? Are there any other routes? And which way do you think I should go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have got it pretty much summed up on your own. One thing I would like to add is you could create custom fields instead of using Event Recievers:

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/custom-field-types-as-an-alternative-way-for-list-item-event-handling-in-sharepoint/

This way you wont have to recreate all the CRUD operations.